# Objects fade away on desktop on Ubuntu 14.04, after reinstalling Nvidia 340.24 driver

Tags: drivers, 14.04, nvidia

After installing the NVIDIA proprietary 340.24 driver, I've got flickering objects on the screen. I decided to reinstall the driver availble on the repositories and now I get everything fading out, returning to light only when I pass the mouse over.

What is the problem and waht can be done?

Comment: Did you remove the Nvidia driver? `apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`

Answer (score 0):

although not on ubuntu, i have notice 340.24 has a lot of bugs when compare to 331.89,

i have small intermittent pauses,
firefox would flicker on certain pages aftwe going back page.
mouse selection in menu lags.
nautilus lags in showing folders.

best revert back to older driver and report bug to nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ppa, this fix NVIDIA flickering problems.

I've aready tested with 340.29, 340.32. Working right.

add-apt-repository ppa:townsend/compiz-nvidia-refresh-test

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Done! Now Reboot